# OSPF on tunnel interfaces

Tags: ospf, tunnel, gre

Can I keep different tunnel interfaces in different OSPF areas. Keep in mind that the physical interface is going to be the same

Comment: Short answer:  Yes.

Comment: It's a valid configuration, just make very sure that the routes to the tunnel endpoints aren't superseded by routes learned via OSPF or you'll have a bad time.

Comment: Just remember that OSPF requires Area-to-Area traffic to pass through Area 0. You cannot have the tunnels of Area 1, Area 2, and Area 3 connect together on a router and be able to pass routes to each other unless the router also has an interface in Area 0.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, what's important to the router is layer 3 interfaces.

You can think of a layer 3 interface as a logical construct, which can be be tied to a VLAN, physical or tunnel interface.

Answer (score 0):

A large OSPF domain is typically broken into separate areas to restrict the propagation of routes and reduce the amount of resources required by each router to maintain its link state database. Each area is connected to a central backbone, area zero. Splitting them into more manageable areas can help speed traffic along to it's destination.
 So answering your question, Yes you can keep different tunnel interfaces in different OSPF areas. 
You can check out the following link if its helpful:
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security-vpn/ipsec-negotiation-ike-protocols/14381-gre-ipsec-ospf.html